# How do I make my positive integer become negative and stay negative until the end of my action?

Tags: java

I'm trying to test out removing an image from the screen by converting its x and y values into negative values (my screen is a 500 by 500 and cannot be resized) and then returning it to the screen in the next slide by converting the x and y values back into positives so I can then convert them back to negative to remove them again.

In one class (which shows a red pointer on the screen that I can move to the boundaries of other items) I have this:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
public void checkBoundariesTouching() {
    NextSlide next = MainFrame.getSlide();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        if (getBounds().intersects(next.getBounds())) {
            MainFrame.slide += 1;
```

In my MainFrame, this slide increase changes the background to make my slides interesting and changes the writing shown.

I have another class that produces black rectangles that I remove one by one to uncover a bullet point of writing that I then explain. I remove the rectangles like this:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
public class BlackRectangle extends Entity {

public BlackRectangle(int x, int y) {
    super(x, y);

}    
public void update() {
    int slide = MainFrame.getSlide();
    checkBoundariesTouching();
    if (slide >= 2) {
        if (x < 0) {
            x = -x;
        }
        if (y < 0) {
            y = -y;
        }
        checkBoundariesTouching();
    }
}

public void checkBoundariesTouching() {

    Pointer pointer = MainFrame.getPointer();
    NextSlide next = MainFrame.getSlide();
    if (getBounds().intersects(pointer.getBounds())) {
        x = -x;
        y = -y;


    }
```

When the slide is equal to 1, I can remove the black squares without problem. However, when I have increased to the next slide (from slide 2 onwards) when the pointer is touching a black rectangle, it is moved off screeen but once I move the pointer away from it, the black rectangle returns and covers the information. Is there a way I can fix this code as it stands only changing the update method?

Comment: Please Post [**SSCCE**](http://sscce.org/) for better help.

Comment: @Azad, I think I have posted all the related sections, I can't think of what else could be missing.

Comment: @Stephen C I am not being tested on Java. I do need to talk about the problems I encountered trying out a new software that beginners and experts can use at different levels in my presentation, so that would be mentioned.

Comment: `java.awt.Rectangle` implements `intersects()`.

Comment: @trashgod, I am able to remove the black rectangles using getBounds, my main issue is the black rectangle returning when I move the pointer way from it (I am moving the pointer using KeyEvent by the way.)

Comment: I just thought `java.awt.Rectangle` would make your [sscce](http://sscce.org/) more readable.

Answer (score 2):

> I admit I do not know very much Java at all and started two days ago but I am trying to use Java code for my presentation to prove that I can grasp basic concepts of a program in a short space of time and build on it as I go along (I need to prove this to get into my course at uni that has nothing to do with Computer Science.)

I would seriously counsel you NOT to do this.

If the prerequisites for the course are that you have a basic grasp of programming ... and you don't have that basic grasp ... then you are going to get into real problems down the track.  Especially, since if this is not a CS course, they are UNLIKELY to help you out if you run into problems due to poor programming skills.

OTOH, if the problem is that you are competent at (say) C# and not at Java, then the right solution is to fork out the money for a developer license.  'Cos you are going to need it in order to do the development work as part of your course ... or in the future.

(But surely you can find a cheaper way of getting a Visual Studio license.  I can get "Visual Studio Professional 2012 with MSDN" from the MS Store for less than $1.2k AUD ... with no student discount.)

---

I acknowledge your point that they are not specifically testing your Java competence.  They are, however testing, you on your general competence as a programmer.  And surely that includes your ability to **choose the right tool for the job** ... which includes not trying to do some programming to a tight deadline in a programming language that you are not familiar with!!

Comment: I don't need programming for the course. I am applying for Chemical Engineering. They just want to see if I can learn basics of a program in a short space of time and what I've learnt from problems I've come up against. I don't have the money to buy the actual software we would use (AspenOne), get training and really wow them when I will be getting to that stage on my course anyway. I wouldn't try this if it was that important that I had a really high level understanding in Java as a prerequisite.

Comment: I think you are making a mistake.  I think you may have serious difficulties demonstrating your competency to them.  However, that's your choice.  Good luck.

Comment: As I have mentioned, I cannot buy AspenOne. So thanks and I'll continue to give this a shot.

Answer (score 1):

If the code works fine when slide = 1, I would suggest removing this:

```
if (slide >= 2) {
    if (x < 0) {
        x = -x;
    }
    if (y < 0) {
        y = -y;
    }
    checkBoundariesTouching();
}
```

If you need that code to move the boxes back on the screen, you can put the if statements inside a separate method and call that method when you change slides.

Comment: I tried separating this into public static void resetCovers(){} so I could create a getter and use it in my pointer class (the first piece of code up there) but that didn't work. Maybe I am calling it wrong?

Comment: Because you want the method to run on each individual instance of the class, you don't want static in the method header.
Try  public void resetCovers(){}

Answer (score 0):

Check for an additional condition within the update method. The method must look like this one below:-

```
        public void update() {
            int slide = MainFrame.getSlide();
            checkBoundariesTouching();
            if (slide >= 2) {
                if (x < 0) {
                    x = x*-1;
                }
                if (y < 0) {
                    y = y*-1;
                }


            }
        }


public void checkBoundariesTouching() {

    Pointer pointer = MainFrame.getPointer();
    NextSlide next = MainFrame.getSlide();
    if (getBounds().intersects(pointer.getBounds())) {
    if(x>0){
        x = -x;
           }
    if(y>0){
        y = -y;
           }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I have now switched from using "-" to using "*-1". I have tried using different conditions but none of them have worked so far. What I thought would work is mentioning the increase in slide but I don't think it can be used as a condition (or maybe it can but not using "for" or "if".)

Comment: After trying this, my pointer didn't remove the rectangles at all now; I think I need that second checkBoundariesTouching(); that I already have in my code.

Comment: Kindly try this code and see if it works as you want it to. The glitch should be within the checkBoundariesTouching() method.

Comment: Trying that, the Rectangles are not removed at all from slide 2 onwards.

Comment: @justprogrammingsomething how about this one please try it and see if it works.